# Where to find Roslyn DEBUGGER Syntax Visualizer?

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

My understanding is that a sample project used to come with the [Roslyn SDK](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2ddb7240-5249-4c8c-969e-5d05823bcb89)  that you could compile and install manually into your `Visual Studio 2015/Visualizers` folder. But I have installed the SDK and am unable to find it.

There is [this folder](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/56f605c41915317ccdb925f66974ee52282609e7/src/Tools/Source) in the Roslyn git repo but none of those appears to be the ***debugger*** syntax visualizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't find it, it was removed, because [it stopped working due to changes in Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1680#issuecomment-87841663):

> There used to be a debugger visualizer sample in early versions of Roslyn CTP when syntax trees and nodes were serializable. We removed the serialization support for nodes at some point. Since debugger visualizers are required to run in a separate app domain, we would need nodes to be serializable to make this work correctly again.

Comment: What a pity. It could be very usefull.